# Using session var to publish data in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

**Background to what I'm implementing**
There is a list of items each generated from a Mongodb collection. Each of the item has a book/apply option which takes the user to a form handling page. Now each of the items have different locations available , thus I want to check the ownership of the locations through a session var which has the ID from the parent object on the previous page. If there is a match, the location is displayed as a option in a drop down list.

The code to filter the result is :

```
Meteor.publish('locations', function(id) {
  return Locations.find({
      $or: [
        { owner: id }
      ]
    });
});
```

and

```
Meteor.subscribe('locations', Session.get('id'));
```

> When I use a string in place of id to compare, the code works but when
>   I plan to use a session var it is not able to. Any idea why is that
>   happening.

Comment: where and when are you setting the session variable?

Comment: Subscriptions will not automatically re-subscribe when one of its arguments changes. You have to put it inside a reactive computation with `Tracker.autorun()`: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_subscribe